# php operators , this example has confused me

Tags: php, operators

The code below:

```
$currentTime = 10;
$currentDayText = 'Fri';
$roomid = 25;

var_dump($currentTime > 6); //true
var_dump($currentDayText == 'Fri'); //true
var_dump($roomid == 25); //true
var_dump($roomid == 25 && $currentDaytext == 'Fri' && $currentTime > 6); //false?
```

The example above has 3 declared variables, each one when wrapped in the method var_dump() relates to true. However if I group all 3 in one condition it evaluates to false. Could somebody kindly explain why so I can understand why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$currentDayText` != `$currentDaytext`

Comment: no operator issues, just  a typo

Comment: I see, dammit! face palms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$currentDaytext` is undefined, so it's implicitly false. The variable you defined and assigned `true` to is `$currentDayText` - notice the capital T.

If you fix that mistake, applying `&&` to three expressions that evaluate as true will indeed evaluated to true too.

Answer (score 0):

`$currentDaytext == 'Fri'` should be `$currentDayText == 'Fri'` in your last line. Capital "Text".